# jQuery Dropdown Menu - Superfish Submenu Alignment

Tags: jquery, css, superfish

I have a site with Superfish. The problem is that I have a lot of menu items and submenu items, so when you hover on, for example, the last item of the main menu, its submenu is so long that it goes off the window. I was wondering if there was a way to make it so the submenu goes towards the top of the window instead of the bottom.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the top position of the submenu to auto and instead gave it a bottom position.